# Writing to file alternating between contents of two other separate files

Tags: python, file, nested, alternate

I have two files cats.txt and dogs.txt and I want to alternate between the two creating a third file that contains the content of cats and dogs in an alternating sequence. I solved the problem like this:

```
def combiningFiles():
    cats = []
    dogs = []
    catsIter = iter(cats)
    dogsIter = iter(dogs)

    with open('cats.txt', 'r') as catFile:
        for line in catFile:
            cats.append(line)

    with open('dogs.txt', 'r') as dogFile:
        for line in dogFile:
            dogs.append(line)

    with open('catsAndDogs.txt', 'w') as file:
        for i in range(10):
            if i % 2 == 1:
                file.write(next(catsIter))
            if i % 2 == 0:
                file.write(next(dogsIter))

combiningFiles()
```

When reading the catsAndDogs.txt file it should output something like this:

```
Cat breed 1
Dog breed 1
Cat breed 2
Dog breed 2
Cat breed 3
Dog breed 3
# and so on
```

**I was wondering if there is a way to loop through two files at the same time.** Ouputing this alternating sequence into a third file is my goal, which is achieved with the code above, but is there a **shorter** way to do so?

Comment: The first code won't run. You're not calling the function, and relying on globals that don't exist.

Comment: I left out the call when pasting it here. Im not sure what you are aiming at, the first code does what I want it to, but it is probably a bad way to solve it..

Answer (score 2):

Well I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly but it seems to me the zip function could do this. And it is possible to open all files on the same line:

```
with open('cats.txt', 'r') as catFile, open('dogs.txt', 'r') as dogFile, open('catsAndDogs.txt', 'w') as file:
    cat_list = [line for line in catFile]
    dog_list = [line for line in dogFile]
    for cat, dog in zip(cat_list, dog_list):
        file.write(cat + '\n')
        file.write(dog + '\n')
```

### Edit:

Better and more optimized version based on comments:

```
with open('cats.txt') as cats, open('dogs.txt') as dogs, open ('animals.txt', 'w') as animals:
    for cat, dog in zip(cats, dogs):
        animals.write(cat.strip() + '\n')
        animals.write(dog.strip() + '\n')
```

#### Note

If your lists are not going to be the same length and you really need to iterate over all elements in the longest list you can use zip_longest from the itertools module. In this case None will be used to fill in the remaining values from the shortest list which you can easily account for with an if statement.

Comment: You can also just call `readlines`, but you really shouldn't. Files are already iterable. Why not just zip them together directly? That way you don't have to copy the entire contents into memory all at once

Comment: This was great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you guarantee that the number of lines in the files `cats.txt` and `dogs.txt` is the same? If yes, you can `zip` the contents of the two lists `cats` and `dogs`. Also, you can directly read the contents of the files using the `readline` method rather than appending each line to an initially empty list.

```
def combingFiles():

    # directly read the lines in the files
    # rather than appending repeatedly
    with open('cats.txt') as catFile:
        cats = catFile.readlines()
    with open('dogs.txt') as dogFile:
        dogs = dogFile.readlines()

    # https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip
    with open('catsAndDogs.txt', 'w') as cdFile:
        for cat_line, dog_line in zip(cats, dogs):
            print(cat_line, end = '', file = cdFile)
            print(dog_line, end = '', file = cdFile)
```

Sample input and output:

```
$ cat cats.txt
twenty-one
twenty-two
twenty-three
twenty-four

$ cat dogs.txt
thirty-one
thirty-two
thirty-three
thirty-four

$ cat catsAndDogs.txt
twenty-one
thirty-one
twenty-two
thirty-two
twenty-three
thirty-three
twenty-four
thirty-four
```

Comment: This was great as well! Thank you! I will check the zip function!